# Multiplatform Game-Center

Tags: android, iphone

To build an app where we want to use some integration with Facebook, multiple opponents, achievements and stuff... we are looking for the best way to do this.

Now, Apple has there game center which won't works with Android same will probably hold with for the Google counter part. What are the best alternatives for building such a system and/or implementing one in an Android and iOs environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should search for OpenFeint , you can look at the below post

http://www.iphonenuts.com/game-center-v-openfeint

Comment: Openfeint is being discontinued since being bought by GREE.  GREE will probably push their own solution.

Comment: Simon, they supply OpenFeint SDK for Android 1.10.2 and their new feature Gamefeed. But i dont know its free or not

Comment: Until December 14th, when the service will stop.